# After updating to macOS Catalina, and re-installing Anaconda, Jupyter is not opening up

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

I did update to macOS Catalina, re-installed Anaconda, and then did

```
Enter: export PATH='/Users/myname/anaconda3/bin:$PATH'
Enter: conda init zsh
```

But still the jupyter does not show up. an editor shows up that says:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://localhost:8889/tree?token=32553c17bf2edd3f1496cc6b431bab6ac1d1aa6ee9ca1f5f" />
    <title>Opening Jupyter Notebook</title>
    <script>
      setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = "http://localhost:8889/tree?token=32553c17bf2edd3f1496cc6b431bab6ac1d1aa6ee9ca1f5f";
      }, 1000);
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>
    This page should redirect you to Jupyter Notebook. If it doesn't,
    <a href="http://localhost:8889/tree?token=32553c17bf2edd3f1496cc6b431bab6ac1d1aa6ee9ca1f5f">click here to go to Jupyter</a>.
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

So, chrome does not automatically go to the jupyter thing where we do stuff, I should copy-paste
the address `http://localhost:8889/tree?token=32553c17bf2edd3f1496cc6b431bab6ac1d1aa6ee9ca1f5f`
in the text above directly into the address bar of Chrome!

Any solution?

Comment: In your terminal could you type `which python` and see what the output is?

Comment: /Users/hn/anaconda3/bin/python